# lxml-html parse very deeply tag level python

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

**I need to get image sources from html tag using lxml python module.**
Basically the url I'm requesting is - https://aeroparque.shopdutyfree.com/en/catalogsearch/result/?q=chocolate
and I only need to get the image source of any picture of products using lxml.
my code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

.xpath('//a[@class="product photo product-item-photo"]/img[@class="product-image-photo"]/@src/text()')
for i in image:
        print(i)
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: it's not return what I'm want. i need the image source, and get nothing in return

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make that clear. Thanks.

Comment: I've just edited, is it clear enough?

Comment: It would be better if you say that you get an empty string (if that's what is happening). I assume that's what you get, but I don't know for sure, since "I get nothing" might mean that your search doesn't find any HTML nodes. The more precise you can make a problem statement, the easier it is to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`/@src` returns the value of the `src` attribute, which is a simple string. Adding `/text()` will return nothing, since `text()` extracts the text from an element, not an attribute.

Comment: can you enter to the link and see if you can post here the generic path of the images?

Comment: The XPath search (without `/text()`) works fine in the Firefox webconsole. (You can do an XPath search with `$x('....')`)